# How to Get all uppercase characters from cell in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I want all **capital letters** .. 
JUST LIKE,
**Casey Richard Omar W= CROW** ,...
**Processing of Dimensional Stone = PDS**

like all capital letters or **shortname**

[image]

Comment: To get an answer, you have to show what you've tried.

Comment: `VBA` can be used or not?

Comment: @ShrivallabhaRedij i have triend of first uppercase letter position.. like... =MIN(IF(ISERROR(FIND(CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT("65:90"))),A1)),"",FIND(CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT("65:90"))),A1)))

Comment: Could your problem be better defined as extracting the initials, instead of the letters in capital? Let's say from `CaSey RicHard Omar W`, do you want to extract `CSRHOW` the letters in capital or `CROW` the initials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Regular Expressions to do this

```
Sub ExampleRegExp()
    Dim RegExp As Object
    Dim str As String

    str = "Casey Richard Omar W"

    Set RegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RegExp
        .Global = False
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "([a-z]+)|(\s)"

        Do While .test(str) = True
            str = .Replace(str, vbNullString)
        Loop

        MsgBox str
    End With
End Sub
```

Or using it as a UDF

```
Function GetUpperCase(str As String) As String
    Dim RegExp As Object

    Set RegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RegExp
        .Global = False
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "([a-z]+)|(\s)"

        Do While .test(str) = True
            str = .Replace(str, vbNullString)
        Loop

        GetUpperCase = str
    End With
End Function
```

in `A2` I've entered `=GetUpperCase(A1)`

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 2016, which contains the useful function `CONCAT`, then you can use this array formula: (line breaks added for readability)

```
= CONCAT(MID(A1,MODE.MULT(IF(ABS(CODE(MID(A1,
  COLUMN(INDEX(1:1,1):INDEX(1:1,LEN(A1))),1))-77.5)<13,
  COLUMN(INDEX(1:1,1):INDEX(1:1,LEN(A1)))*{1;1})),1))
```

Otherwise, as already provided, VBA or formula with a bunch of `SUBSTITUTE`s are required.

Comment: Why the downvote? I realize the question states they are using Excel 2007, just giving this answer for other users who may have Excel 2016 who are looking for a similar answer at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this question is more about how to create a short name, with the initials of the names.

If that is the case then try this formula:

```
    = CONCATENATE( LEFT( $A1 ),
    IFERROR( MID( $A1, 1 + SEARCH( "‡", SUBSTITUTE( $A1, " ", "‡", 1 ) ), 1 ), "" ),
    IFERROR( MID( $A1, 1 + SEARCH( "‡", SUBSTITUTE( $A1, " ", "‡", 2 ) ), 1 ), "" ),
    IFERROR( MID( $A1, 1 + SEARCH( "‡", SUBSTITUTE( $A1, " ", "‡", 3 ) ), 1 ), "" ),
    IFERROR( MID( $A1, 1 + SEARCH( "‡", SUBSTITUTE( $A1, " ", "‡", 4 ) ), 1 ), "" ) )
```

If the name has more than four words then you can just add more lines, like:

```
    IFERROR( MID( $A1, 1 + SEARCH( "‡", SUBSTITUTE( $A1, " ", "‡", # ) ), 1 ), "" ),
```

were `#` represents the word number

If any of the words contain the character `‡`, just changed it to any other uncommon character.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using VBA, @Harun24HR's solution is a messy, but very effective one.
Here's a version with extra special characters for those in need:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE([@Navn],"a",""),"b",""),"c",""),"d",""),"e",""),"f",""),"g",""),"h",""),"i",""),"j",""),"k",""),"l",""),"m",""),"n",""),"o",""),"p",""),"q",""),"r",""),"s",""),"t",""),"u",""),"v",""),"w",""),"x",""),"y",""),"z",""),"æ",""),"ø",""),"å",""),"á",""),"ç",""),"é",""),"í",""),"ó",""),"ú",""),"-","")," ","")
```

With ; instead of , (for Excel installations in other languages):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE([@Navn];"a";"");"b";"");"c";"");"d";"");"e";"");"f";"");"g";"");"h";"");"i";"");"j";"");"k";"");"l";"");"m";"");"n";"");"o";"");"p";"");"q";"");"r";"");"s";"");"t";"");"u";"");"v";"");"w";"");"x";"");"y";"");"z";"");"æ";"");"ø";"");"å";"");"á";"");"ç";"");"é";"");"í";"");"ó";"");"ú";"");"-";"");" ";"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following formula---

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"a",""),"b",""),"c",""),"d",""),"e",""),"f",""),"g",""),"h",""),"i",""),"j",""),"k",""),"l",""),"m",""),"n",""),"o",""),"p",""),"q",""),"r",""),"s",""),"t",""),"u",""),"v",""),"w",""),"x",""),"y",""),"z","")," ","")
```

[image]

Comment: Effective, but this formula makes me shudder a bit haha.

Comment: Also this doesn't work if the string contains special characters such as periods or colons, etc. Not sure if the OP cares or not though. Just pointing it out.

Comment: Then you have to add that special character into the formula. By using `VBA` you can achieve it very easily. But using only excel formulas it is difficult. So formular will be more longer for more character.

Answer (score -3):

Sounds like you're looking for the `=UPPER()` formula

Comment: no, i want to find all capital letters like, Casey Richard Omar W  =CROW,  Processing of Dimensional Stone = PDS

Comment: @IHaveQuestion Abvios now, that the question has been edited! harun24hr's answer is what I would do in that case is not using a VBA Loop